# Current value of compound interest

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

How can I calculate the current value of a sum deposited in a past date, with a fixed interest rate?

For example, if $1,000 were deposited on 1/1/2000 in an account which pays a 3% annual interest rate, how much would they be worth today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## COMPOUND INTEREST:

- **`cell F6:` `=B6*(1+C6)^(YEARFRAC(A6,TODAY()))`**
- **`cell G6:` `=B6*(1+C6/4)^(4*YEARFRAC(A6,TODAY()))`**
- **`cell H6:` `=B6*(1+C6/12)^(12*YEARFRAC(A6,TODAY()))`**
- **`cell I6:` `=B6*(1+C6)^(ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(A6,TODAY()),0))`**
- **`cell J6:` `=B6*(1+C6/4)^(4*ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(A6,TODAY()),0))`**
- **`cell K6:` `=B6*(1+C6/12)^(12*ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(A6,TODAY()),0))`**

[image: 2]

### _______________________________________________________________

## INTEREST MULTIPLIED BY YEARS:

- **up to today's date:**


  ```
  =B2 + C2/100*B2 * YEARFRAC(A2; TODAY())
  ```
- **up to to the start of new anual period (eg. from 01.01.2000 to 31.12.2018):**


  ```
  =B2 + C2/100*B2 * ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(A2; TODAY()); 0)
  ```

[image: 4]

Comment: Many thanks! Just one difficulty: I had to use 3 (and not 3%) under annual rate in order to get to the same result. Or delete the "/100".

Comment: yup, **C2** was custom formatted with `@%` mask

Comment: hmmm... actually the formula doesn't answer my question, as it only calculates the interest * years. It does not calculate the compound interest. For the example above, the result should have been $1757 and not $1571

Comment: @Stacko answer updated

Comment: Thanks again. The answer now indeed enables an accurate calculation of the compound interest. I still didn't mark it as solved with a faint hope someone comes with a Google Sheets function that calculates current value of compound interest.

Comment: @Stacko pls define "current"

Comment: Current = today

Comment: @Stacko well thats **F6** from 1st image of my answer... `=YEARFRAC(A6,TODAY())` calculates whole period between deposit day and today. if you need SUPER-current value precise to exact second of today's day then change `TODAY()` to `NOW()`

Comment: Agree. I wrote above that your answer enables an accurate calculation. I was just wondering if a Google Sheets formula (similar to NPV, PMT) existed, to calculate current value of compound interest. Since nobody suggested one, I marked the question solved. Thanks!